# csv/txt file content comparison in ruby. - for multiple pairs of files

Tags: ruby, file, text, csv, compare

Its like there are mutliple pairs of files that needs to be compared. Then a result text file will display if there are pairs that have different contents, and will also display the differences.

Please help if there is existing code/application that can do this. Or if its possible in ruby? If yes, how and where should I start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another tool may help you better - or is there a reason why you need ruby?

Some examples:

- [kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (free)
- [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com/) (
- [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) (unix tool)

See also [wikipedia for more diff tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Free_file_comparison_tools)

Comment: thanks. My boss prefer to develop own code so we can customize to functions that we want (stated above). Ruby is existing program that is installed to our machine, and if we request for other programs, will take long time to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://markmcb.com/2008/11/04/ruby-on-rails-diff-text-to-html-ins-and-del/

Comment: Thanks. that looks awesome but I am not really familiar with ruby on rails, guess it needs other installation process. Do you know anything like that for ruby?

Comment: This is almost pure ruby. The only rails stuff is RAILS_ROOT and Rails.root. Just replace that with your directory name